# Persist client dependent data on Facebook db?

Tags: database, facebook, persistence

I'm totally new to fb coding. For a new project, I would like to create a fb app. The app is multi tenant, authorisation and authentication is carried out by fb. That's easy.

However, I would like to persistent data the user enters *within* fb. For example, there's a user dependent attribute 'mood'. The user may enter any string. Now my question: any possibility to persist such info on fb db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to control the behavior or store the data persistently on FB. Instead you can get the attribute and persist in your sever

You can subscribe to real time data, when ever user modifies any data, you can receive notifications and you can pull the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already suspected that. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I checked your answer. Is the question closed now?